# How to sum of fields in elasticsearch and move another index

Tags: elasticsearch

Below is my mapping.I want to sum of payment if their names are equal. And put that in payment field. Then, I want collect data like this.

```
{
  "person" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "dynamic_templates" : [
        {
          "strings" : {
            "match_mapping_type" : "string",
            "mapping" : {
              "type" : "keyword"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "properties" : {
        "userid" : {
          "type" : "keyword"
        },
        "name" : {
          "type" : "keyword"
        },
        "payment" : {
          "type" : "keyword",
          "fields" : {
            "numeric" : {
              "type" : "integer"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As an example

Index1

```
userid  name   payment
1234    Marco    20
2312    Sylvia   50
5653    Ruben    35
1234    Marco    30
```

Expected Result

Index1

```
userid  name   payment
1234    Marco    50
2312    Sylvia   50
5653    Ruben    35
```

Comment: You want to store the result in a new index, right? Besides, the two userid for Marco are not equal, do you want to match by name?

Comment: Sorry I ve miss typed. Userids are same. But match by name yes. Userid is may not be able to unique in this concept.

Comment: Yes result will be in new index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is to leverage the [Transform API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/transform-overview.html). That will run an aggregation query over your data and store the aggregated results into a new index.

```
PUT _transform/person_payments
{
  "source": {
    "index": "person",
    "query": {
      "match_all": {}
      }
    }
  },
  "pivot": {
    "group_by": {
      "name": {
        "terms": {
          "field": "name"
        }
      }
    },
    "aggregations": {
      "sum_payments": {
        "sum": {
          "field": "payment.numeric"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "person_payments"
  }
}
```

When created, you can start the transform with `POST _transform/person_payments/_start` and when done you'll have a new index called `person_payments` with the data you need.

Comment: One more thing may i ask ? How to call this from python ? I have found that using self.es.transform.put_transform(). This function requires transform id and some other params ?

Comment: `transform_id: person_payments` and body the whole JSON payload

Comment: Thank you so much. I was thinking I would need the other params but it worked just giving transform id and body

Comment: That's fantastic!!