# SQL DISTINCT Pair of Values in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to ask how to use **SQL DISTINCT Pair of Values in Elasticsearch**. Like below,

```
SELECT distinct username, city from country_table
```

I can run below query for just one field. In the aggs json, I can only see "username" fields.

**But I need DISTINCT username, city pair.**

```
{
  "_source": ["username","city"]
  "aggs": {
     "unique_ids": 
        {
           "terms": { "fields": "username" }
        }
  }
}
```

How can i solve this ?

Thanks for answering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [multi_terms aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch//reference/7.12/search-aggregations-bucket-multi-terms-aggregation.html)

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "unique_pair": {
      "multi_terms": {
        "terms": [
          {
            "field": "username"
          },
          {
            "field": "city"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It is worth mentioning that this is only available from 7.12 onwards

Comment: yes, thats the answer but may i ask a question ? Is it possible to send the result to another index ? I mean results (username, city)  in another index ?

Comment: @kndr yes you can do that [using transforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66353599/how-to-sum-of-fields-in-elasticsearch-and-move-another-index/66354448#66354448)

Comment: I have tried the answer. Thats run perfectly. But if i use this "aggs" in transform api "aggregations". I get "unsupported aggregation type [multi_terms]" @Val