# how to store aggregations query result to elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

[pipeline.conf]

```
input {
  pipeline {
    address => "bin"
  }
}

filter {
  elasticsearch {
    index => "access_index"
    hosts => ["http://elasticsearch:9200"]
    query_template => "/usr/share/logstash/pipeline/template.json"
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    index => "calculate_index"
    hosts => ["http://elasticsearch:9200"]
  }
}
```

[template.json]

```
{
    "size" : 0,
    "aggs" : {
        "group_by_remote_addr" : {
            "terms" : {
                "field" : "remote_addr.keyword"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[with curl]

```
curl -XGET "localhost:9200/access_index/_search?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
    "size" : 0,
    "aggs" : {
        "group_by_remote_addr" : {
            "terms" : {
                "field" : "remote_addr.keyword"
            }
        }
    }
}
'
```

and this is curl result
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40fNF.png)

I want to store aggregations query result to elasticsearch. But i don't know how to do.

Also, how to extract only buckets key value?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I personally haven't done data transforming but it is worth to read about it.

[elasticsearch transforms](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/transforms.html)

And you may use transform API

[elasticsearch transform apis](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/transform-apis.html)

As far as I read, you can take the data from a source index and deliver it to a new index and your source index stays intact.

Comment: Here is an example of how to do it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66354448/4604579

Comment: Thanks for your help. Let's give it a try.